# Exception to viewing deleted post rules

Tags: discussion, deleted-questions, review-audits

While making reviews I encountered a test which was based on a deleted [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19236257/jquery-wont-work-with-firefox-or-ie).

The [rules](https://stackoverflow.com/help/deleted-answers) for deleted posts says:

> Once a post has been deleted, it will disappear for all users except
>   developers, moderators, and users with over 10,000 reputation.

So doesn't using that post on a user with below 10k rep (which includes me) violate the stated rule? Or am I being too punctilious?

Comment: I vote for "puntilicious" :-)

Answer (score 4):

It's an audit.  The poor quality post was selected as an example of a bad post that should have actions taken against it.

It's very much an intentional design decision to display the text of that deleted post to non-10k users.

The user card shown to you in the review audit is anonymized (it's a fake), so you can't see who the *actual* author is (unless you have the 10k rep to go to the link and see the real user).

Comment: Concurred but doesn't that intentional design break the stated rule? Or it could've been mentioned, "except...for audit purposes..."

Comment: @hus787 I don't think the goal of the help pages is to raise more questions. By mentioning the review panel there you're just going to confuse users. Only deleted posts which were deleted due to certain flags even get chosen, so it's not really relevant information to most users.

Comment: @hus I vote for "puntilicious" :-)

Comment: @hus787 They can't *really* see the post, at least not properly, with all of the information shown on any other answer.  I don't see any compelling reason for it to be worth the confusion it would cause most people reading that information.

Comment: @Servy let me assure you that I really can see that particular post(not the answers though) now that I have passed the test. All the comments(not the deleted ones), votes, who closed it and the date and time.

Comment: @hus787 But not the author, or the revision history, or the answers, or the score (you aren't seeing the *real* score), etc.  You're seeing some of the information about it, but not *all*.

Comment: @Servy It only gives you fake information while completing the audit. The real information is shown once you've completed it.

Comment: @Servy define real score, if it's -8 then I see it. [This](http://stackoverflow.com/users/2856487/user2856487) is the author. Concurred with the rest.

Comment: @hus787 Okay, and why is that a problem?  What compelling reason is there to change anything?

Comment: @animuson I think that help page in itself is quite esoteric. Therefore shouldn't it be expected from the user to brace themselves for some technical and precise, be it confusing, information.

Comment: @Servy read the question. I precisely mention "violate the stated rule"?

Comment: @hus787 The help pages are there to help users effectively use the site.  It doesn't contain everything about everyting, just the information that is important for them to know about.  If the help pages are technical and precise then users won't read them.  That a very bad thing.

Comment: @Servy With the same line of thought. Why would one think that it is important for the users to know that developer, moderators etc are allowed to view the post? Isn't that technical too?

Comment: @hus787 Not really. It's often important for users to realize that deleting something doesn't mean that it's gone, it's just hidden from regular users.  This means that deleted questions can be undeleted under certain circumstances, or that a deleted post can still be reviewed if needed, so that a user doesn't think that they can delete inappropriate content and then be free of the consequences of that behavior.  Most people expect that deleting something means that it's actually *gone*.

Comment: @hus787 It should be noted that only *you* can view that deleted content inside the audit, and only as long as you have the link. Review audits on deleted posts do not show up in your activity on your profile. So once you leave that audit page, it still qualifies as "disappeared". But that also brings up the point that there are plenty of places where deleted content *can* show up. Suggested edits on a deleted post are still displayed, for example, and users could always copy-paste the content elsewhere. Should we list all those possibilities too? It's meant to apply to the *general case*.

Comment: @animuson My quibble is with the appearance at that point in time, hadn't the tone of the stated rule been exhaustive I wouldn't have raised this question. An *"etc"* would have been suffice, and that *"etc"* would have made it here in meta and be properly addressed.